# How to add navigation controls to Web browser control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the web browser control in C# project to load html pages.

I can navigate back / forward or refresh the page only after right clicking the web page.

How do I add these navigation controls to the web browser itself, so that user can navigate without right clicking.

Answer (score 3):

You can add buttons on your form and wire up their click events to the appropriate actions you need.

```
//if wb is your WebBrowser instance
wb.GoBack();
wb.Refresh();
wb.GoForward();
```